# Find a set $A$ such that $m(\partial A)>0$, but $m(A)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Question**: Find a set $A$ such that $m(\partial A)>0$, but $m(A)=0$.

**My Thought**: Could we just consider the Cantor set, $C$, on $[0,1]$?  Since $m(C)=0$, but the boundary of $C$ would be all of $[0,1]$, except $C$, a set of measure $0$, so $m(\partial C)=1$.  Would this work?

Just out of curiosity, could the opposite be true in some case?  That is, could we find a set with positive Lebesgue measure, but whose boundary has measure $0$?  Or, would the set $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$, where $\epsilon>0$, work?

Thank you!

Comment: The boundary of $C$ isn't all of $[0,1] \setminus C$, but there's a different measure zero subset that might work...

Comment: The boundary of a set is contained in the closure of the set.  So you need to pick a set that isn't closed.  What zero measure sets do you know that aren't closed?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Could something like $(.5-\frac{1}{2^k},.5+\frac{1}{2^k})$ work?

Comment: No.  You might be over thinking it.  Think of a dense set of measure zero.

Comment: .... hmmm, maybe something like $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$?

Comment: Bingo. $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense and measure zero.

Comment: Ah, so then the boundary of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]=[0,1]$, and so has measure $1$.  I see!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\Bbb{Q}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ but $\partial\Bbb{Q}= \overline{\Bbb{Q}}\cap \overline{\Bbb{R}\setminus \Bbb{Q}} =  \Bbb{R}$ has infinite measure.